# SSMS Index Error - Not matching main table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

We have an app that is throwing an error and I was wondering if someone could help me?

We use an out of the box software system and write apps to do things the system cannot do.  This app was working and now it's not.  It's calls a stored procedure that takes the max key and adds one.  It then uses that new key to insert a line into a table (which adjusts inventory to match another table).

```
The error is:
ODBC Call failed.  Cannot insert duplicate key row into 
InventoryAdjustments with unique index IX_InventoryAdjustments_3.  The 
duplicate key value is (      , 100002).  (#2601) [Microsoft][ODBC SQL 
Server Driver][SQL Server] The statement has been terminated.  (#3621)  
[Microsoft][ODBC Sql Server Driver][SQL Server] ITEM123 transaction qty 
corrected.
```

IX_InventoryAdjustments_3 is an Index that says (Unique, Non-Clustered)
100002 is the correct number and there is no duplicate in the table, so I'm confused.

Does anyone know how to change this?  The index is from the out of the box software and I don't think I should change it.  I tried using a crazy high key and it still gets the error.  I don't know how to make the index key match what the table key has.  I know they did some testing because they have keys that are 999,999 and such so that makes it more complicated.  It's adding 3 now to the max and that's where it's coming up with 1,000,002.  The field length is 8 char. I wonder if that has something to do with it?  It's not inserting the item because there is one already.  So why is

```
max(AdjustmentNo) + 3
```

Not working? If I change it to +4 it works for the first one but then the second one it errors out saying there is a duplicate key 1,000,003 (Shouldn't it be higher because I am not adding +1 but +4?)  It's not incrementing by four. If I do SELECT  max(AdjustmentNo)  from InventoryAdjustments I still get 999,999!

The odd thing is the app still works. It doesn't do an insertion in the adjustment table but does the correct insertion in the other tables.  I had someone verify it and they said it looks fine.

It just gives you this error message.  A lot of times they do On Error Resume Next but I'd really like to try to avoid that for obvious reasons.

Thanks.

ETA Info for:

```
SELECT @nextAdjNum = max(AdjustmentNo) + 1 from InventoryAdjustments
INSERT INTO InventoryAdjustments(     AdjustmentNo      --1
                                    , InvItemNo         --2
                                    , TransDate         --3
                                    , CustVendor        --4
                                    , AccountNo         --5
                                    , Reference         --6
                                    , AdjustReason      --7
                                    , Location          --8
                                    , EmpCode           --9
                                    , QtyAdjustedBy     --10
                                    , UnitCost          --11
                                    , TotalCost         --12
                                    , AverageCost       --13
                                    , QtyAdjustedTo     --14
                                    , LastCost          --15
                                )
VALUES(     @nextAdjNum         --1   - AdjustmentNo
        ,  upper(@item)             --2   - InvItemNo
        ,  @transdate           --3   - TransDate
        ,  ''                   --4   - CustVendor
        ,  ''                   --5   - AccountNo
        ,  'ADJUSTMENT'                 --6   - Reference
        ,  @notes               --7   - AdjustReason
        ,  ''                   --8   - Location
        ,  @userCode            --9   - EmpCode
        , @amtToAdd             --10   - QtyAdjustedBy
        , @lastCost             --11   - UnitCost
        , @lastCost * @amtToAdd --12   - TotalCost
        , @lastCost             --13   - AverageCost
        , @qtyOnHand            --14   - QtyAdjustedTo
        , @lastCost             --15   - LastCost
     )
```

There is a trigger that does...

```
update
  [dbo].[InventoryAdjustments]
Set
  bkey0 = AdjustmentNo + InvItemNo+TransDate,
  bkey1 = InvItemNo + AdjustmentNo,
  bkey2 = CustVendor + AdjustmentNo,
  bkey3 = TransDate + AdjustmentNo
Where
  [dbo].[InventoryAdjustments].recid in (select inserted.recid from inserted)
```

[image]

Comment: Please show the table definition what you're inserting in to and the query you're using to insert.  We need to know if any relevant columns are IDENTITY *(for example)*, and whether your insert statement has an error that may be causing you to be trying to insert two rows with the same key `(      , 100002)` *(which seems likely from your description)*.  Also, using your own logic for an incremental value is fraught with dangers; don't to it, use IDENTITY instead *(depending on your use case you may need one table with the IDENTITY and then use the value from there to insert into this table)*.

Comment: Thank you.  I added information to the original question for you.  What do you mean by identity?  This is what we currently have  SELECT @nextAdjNum = max(AdjustmentNo) + 1 from InventoryAdjustments

Comment: Please post the definition of `IX_InventoryAdjustments_3`. You can get this by generating a Create Script on the index. Also, your problem doesn't have anything to do with SSMS, so that tag should be removed.

Comment: Looks like a composite key -->  duplicate key value is (      , 100002)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property

Comment: CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_InventoryAdjustments_3] ON [dbo].[InventoryAdjustments]
(
 [CustVendor] ASC,
 [AdjustmentNo] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Comment: I don't think I can change that table.  I'm not sure what will happen since it's out of the box software.

Comment: Your insert statement is not thread safe.  If anything else is running in the background you can get in to a case where you read the max value, then something else inserts before you can.  At the the very least use a `TRANSATION` and `WITH(TABLOCKX)`.

Comment: Thank you, MatBailie. I'm not sure how to do that though.  Will that help? It's not grabbing the max number anyways, which is probably a huge part of the problem.  I didn't write any of this, so I apologize.

Comment: What does that trigger do??

Comment: update [dbo].[InventoryAdjustments] 
 Set bkey0 = AdjustmentNo + InvItemNo+TransDate,
  bkey1 = InvItemNo + AdjustmentNo,
  bkey2 = CustVendor + AdjustmentNo,
  bkey3 = TransDate + AdjustmentNo 
 Where [dbo].[InventoryAdjustments].recid in ( select inserted.recid from inserted)   That's from the out of the box software. They use those columns, which are usually the exact same fields as columns in the same table, to do things with.  I'm not exactly sure what it does in this case.)

Comment: Please edit the extra information into your question, rather than in comments. Comments are often hidden and that makes it hard for future readers to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a thread-safe issue, this should work...

But there isn't enough information here to be sure that's the problem.  I presume you're doing more than just the `INSERT`, and so I can't tell if there are other contributing factors.

This at least will ensure that another process doesn't insert a row between your MAX() lookup and the INSERT.

```
INSERT INTO InventoryAdjustments(     AdjustmentNo      --1
                                    , InvItemNo         --2
                                    , TransDate         --3
                                    , CustVendor        --4
                                    , AccountNo         --5
                                    , Reference         --6
                                    , AdjustReason      --7
                                    , Location          --8
                                    , EmpCode           --9
                                    , QtyAdjustedBy     --10
                                    , UnitCost          --11
                                    , TotalCost         --12
                                    , AverageCost       --13
                                    , QtyAdjustedTo     --14
                                    , LastCost          --15
                                )
VALUES(    (SELECT max(CAST(AdjustmentNo AS INT)) + 1 from InventoryAdjustments)         --1   - AdjustmentNo
        ,  upper(@item)             --2   - InvItemNo
        ,  @transdate           --3   - TransDate
        ,  ''                   --4   - CustVendor
        ,  ''                   --5   - AccountNo
        ,  'ADJUSTMENT'                 --6   - Reference
        ,  @notes               --7   - AdjustReason
        ,  ''                   --8   - Location
        ,  @userCode            --9   - EmpCode
        , @amtToAdd             --10   - QtyAdjustedBy
        , @lastCost             --11   - UnitCost
        , @lastCost * @amtToAdd --12   - TotalCost
        , @lastCost             --13   - AverageCost
        , @qtyOnHand            --14   - QtyAdjustedTo
        , @lastCost             --15   - LastCost
     )
```

But you're inherited a very poor deign if you need to do this.  Maintaining an incrementing value is not what you should be doing, due to the need for transaction, etc when doing multi-step actions..

Another option would be the transaction...

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT @nextAdjNum = max(CAST(AdjustmentNo AS INT)) + 1 from InventoryAdjustments WITH(TABLOCKX)

<your insert>

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunaltey I am still getting the same error.  I changed it to +10 just to see and now I get the same error on the second insert.  So it works the first time around and then I do it again and it errors out.  ETA let me try the second option. One sec.

Comment: With the second one, it errors out right away.  Saying 1,000,000 which I know isn't correct.  It's not grabbing the max value. Is that because it's a char?  I can't change that though.

Comment: It doesn't help that you have a `CHAR(8)` field.  Try `SELECT MAX(CAST(AdjustmentNo AS INT)) FROM InventoryAdjustments` and I almost guarantee you get a different result.  As far as a string goes, `'9'` is greater than `'1000000'`.

Comment: I've made a change that deals with the CHAR/INT problem, but it will kneecap performance if use a lot *(It may have to apply the CAST() to every-row and THEN find the max...)*.

Comment: I have to go, good luck.  Back in a few hour if you're still stuck ;)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it. Performance isn't an issue. It's just the head of accounting that needs to do this at the end of the month. So it's not getting hit daily.  But it would save a lot of time if I could get it to work again.

Comment: I get Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1e+006  ' to data type int

Comment: Something seems to be changing it in the background.  If I do a cast or convert it comes up for a second, and then I get the error.  Even if I do these... SELECT CAST(AdjustmentNo AS INT) FROM InventoryAdjustments   Or....
SELECT CONVERT(INT, AdjustmentNo) FROM InventoryAdjustments

Comment: That's what's broken things then, is my bet.  Select the top 100 numbers where they're like '%e%'. Depending on your application you may need to try to delete those.  The actual fix requires investigation beyond the limits of SO.

Comment: That was it! Thank you!  Here I thought it was something super complicated.  Thanks again.  ETA There was one entry with an "e".  I changed it to something random (there's enough chaos in this table where it doesn't matter, plus I think we're ditching this software this year.) and it works.